# Positive semidefinite block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite, block-matrices, schur-complement

Let $M$ be an $n \times n$ block matrix defined as $$M = \begin{bmatrix} A & \mathbf{b} \\ \mathbf{b}^T & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$ where $A$ is an invertible and symmetric $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ matrix, and $\mathbf{b}$ is a column vector of size $(n-1)$. If $M$ is positive semidefinite, what is an equivalent expression in terms of $A$ and $\mathbf{b}$ for this condition to be satisfied?

My guess is that $A$ is positive semidefinite and $1 - \mathbf{b}^T A^{-1} \mathbf{b} \geq 0$. But I am not arriving to prove it. Can anyone clarify if it's true and why?

Comment: Take a look at Jean Gallier's [notes](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~jean/schur-comp.pdf)

Comment: You are close but need to decide on positive definiteness vs positive semi-definiteness.  E.g. if $A$ is not invertible, how can you say the criterion is $1 - \mathbf{b}^T A^{-1} \mathbf{b} \geq 0$?

Comment: [Wikipedia provides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement#Conditions_for_positive_definiteness_and_semi-definiteness) a condition that holds in the case that $A$ fails to be invertible. In particular, in addition to having $1 - b^TA^+b \geq 0$ (where $A^+$ denotes the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse), we also need to have $(I - AA^+)b = 0$. In other words, $b$ must be an element of the column-space of $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For invertible $A$ the proof is easy. It suffices to show the positive definitess of the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}
A^{-1/2} & 0\\
0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
A & b\\
b^T & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
A^{-1/2} & 0\\
0 & 1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
I & A^{-1/2}b\\
b^TA^{-1/2} & 1\end{pmatrix}$$
The last matrix is positive definite iff $I-b^TA^{-1}b>0.$
For nonivertible $A$ we can replace $A$ with $A+n^{-1}I$ and apply the limit procedure. It should work, I hope.